# PHP PDO select with INNER JOIN

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am trying to do a PHP PDO call to my database with an INNER JOIN.

The three joins I'm trying to make is as follows:

```
KC_Orders -- Database Table Name
 --orderNumber -- Relation Field

KC_Payments -- Database Table Name
 --orderNumber -- Relation Field 

KC_OrderStatus -- Database Table Name
 --OrderNumber -- Relation Field
```

I'm wanting to get more info from the tables than just the order number though.

My call to the database is as follows:

```
$sql = "SELECT * from `KC_Orders` INNER JOIN `KC_Payments` INNER JOIN `KC_OrderStatus`";
$ThreeRecentOrders = $db->query($sql);
```

And then in my `foreach` statement I have the following to display the results.

```
<?php foreach($ThreeRecentOrders as $order): ?>
   <?php $orderNumber = $order['orderNumber']; ?>
       <tr>
         <th><?php echo $orderNumber; ?></th>
         <th><?php echo $order['billingFName']; ?> <?php echo $order['billingLName']; ?></th>
         <th>$<?php echo number_format($order['order_total']/100,2); ?></th>
         <th><?php echo $order['statusID']; ?></th>
       </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Now, everything works **BUT** I only have two orders in the system, meaning two rows in each database as of now. `3 database joins` with `2 rows in each field` `3x2=6` I'm getting 6 results in my table in the foreach. It's taking every row and echoing out a result. This clearly was not what I intended. What do I need to add to the database call or sql to resolve this?

Comment: What are you joining on? I'd expect to see something like `... INNER JOIN KC_Payments USING (orderNumber) ... ` or similar, you don't appear to be joining on any foreign key index.

Comment: Perhaps if you add the `ON` clause, as in: `SELECT * FROM KC_Orders o INNER JOIN KC_Payments p ON o.orderNumber = p.orderNumber ... `?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to actually specify which columns to join on

i.e.

```
select * from kc_orders 
    inner join kc_payments 
        on kc_orders.orderNumber = kc_payments.order_number 
    inner join kc_orderStatus 
        on kc_orders.orderNumber = kc_orderStatus.orderNumber
```

Comment: This results in `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` once I reload the page. Which means the call isn't returning anything? Right?

Comment: I guess when you type everything right it works. Thank you though!